# how to add multi HTTPS sites to azure application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Is there a step by step tutorial for adding multisites to azure
application gateway? I need app gateway to direct traffic for the
following **HTTPS** sites

```
test.mydomain.com development.mydomain.com preprod.mydomain.com
```

These sites will then each need to point to a specific webapp

`test.mydomain.com` will need to go to `test.azurewebsites.net
development.mydomain.com` to `development.azurewensites.net` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you expect that one application gateway hosting 3 custom domain websites, then each of custom domain websites point to a specific webapp site.

Firstly, you could map your custom domain DNS name to Azure web apps. And bind SSL certificate for each site. Here is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain). After that, You will find your Azure webapp sites DNS name change to the custom domain. You can access the Azure web apps directly through custom domain DNS name.

For application gateway multiple site hosting, you can set 3 backend pools. Each website can be directed to its own backend pool. The application gateway is serving traffic for `test.mydomain.com` `development.mydomain.com` `preprod.mydomain.com` from 3 backend pools, let's say testPool, devPool, PrePool. Meanwhile, you can add 3 backend listeners, 3 routing rules, 3 HTTP settings and health probes.

It's recommended to configure these things following the PowerShell scripts from this wonderful [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/11/21/setting-up-application-gateway-with-an-app-service-that-uses-azure-active-directory-authentication/) and just ignore the part of Azure Active Directory Authentication.

Once you enable the health probe. You can check the backend health of the Application Gateway. The backend pool should be marked as “Healthy”. If not, then your app is returning a response outside of your probe’s range.

For more details, please refer to this tutorial: [Create an application gateway that hosts multiple web sites using the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-multiple-sites-cli)

Comment: many thanks the SSL certificate is a wildcard one and have uploaded this to the App gateway , do i need to do anything else with regards to the cert?

Comment: If you want to configure end-to-end SSL by App GW, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell)

Comment: is there a way of doing this via the portal ?

Comment: @itye1970 Please check my update and recommend to look at that blog.